# Python: can't start new thread

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, pycharm

I ran into a problem with python threading and when I started to test the maximum limit of threads I ended up with 900 threads max but when I ran this code on another pc it was ok with up to **500,000** threads

maybe something wrong with registry files !?

Platform: Windows

```
from threading import Thread, activeCount
from time import sleep

def x():
    sleep(1000)
    print('END')

for i in range(5000):
    Thread(target=x).start()
    print (activeCount())
```

and Output is :

```
890
891
892
893
894
895
896
897
898
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TAS02/PycharmProjects/All_Projects/tst.py", line 38, in <module>
    Thread(target=x).start()
  File "C:\Users\TAS02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 852, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

Comment: Seems like you reach limit of threads in your OS.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply
i could run about 500,000 threads in few months ago but today when i tested it I faced this error

Comment: There's no reason to run even 100 threads, it won't speed up your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that windows 64-bit has some problems with python 32-bit and that was the Problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

As said above, I think this is to do with OS limits. It's difficult to compare against another machine without knowing the details but things like is it 32/64bit, RAM size, OS limits can all have an impact. I suspect that python is using a lot of memory so Windows is limiting it. The link below may help you to find out what the limit is for threads.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/testlimit

Comment: i tested my computer with testlimit and it was ok with up to 500,000 threads but when i run my python application i cant get more than 1000 threads